# Point of defining affine spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

So I’m doing my first bachelor mathematics. And for our linear algebra and geometry course. We defined abstract affine spaces/surfaces axiomatically. To then prove that with papus’s axioma (I think) you have a vector space. What’s the point of doing all this? To then just get to a vector space anyway?